# Hiding Navigation bar short everything in view up

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, xcode-storyboard

I have the following storyboard setup:

StoryBoard :

[image]

I'm hiding the navigation and tool bars upon tap, however the UITextView shifts up when the navigation bars disappear.

```
    lyrics.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "show_fdw_bck"))

    func show_fdw_bck () {
    print("screen tapped")
    if SongMgr.settings2 == false {
        fwdappear.hidden = true
        bckappear.hidden = true
        navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
        navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: false)
        //lyrics.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 80, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 20, height: self.view.frame.size.width)
        SongMgr.settings2 = true
    } else {
        fwdappear.hidden = false
        bckappear.hidden = false
        navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
        navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: false)
        //lyrics.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 20, height: self.view.frame.size.width)

        SongMgr.settings2 = false
    }

}
```

I attempted to change the order of objects in scene, moving the textview to bottom of View solves the problem, but it hides the UIButtons. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that your `UITextView` shifts up is because the constraints remain the same. There are a couple of ways you can go about fixing this, one option will be to set an `IBOutlet` for the top margin of your `UITextView` and then setting the `constant` property to be +64 (the height of the nav bar) of what it currently is.

Another way to do it is to redo your constraints for the UITextView in the storyboard and set different priorities to specific ones as needed.

Comment: Thank you, i had no idea you could change Layout Constraint in code. Adding the following solved my problem  `@IBOutlet weak var TopMargin: NSLayoutConstraint!` and `TopMargin.constant = TopMargin.constant - 44`.